# Was charged on a failed ERC20 swap via 0x exchange

Tags: fees, failed-transaction

0.15 ether gone to miners.
Possible to get a refund from 0x?
It was a smart contract failure.

Comment: Do you have the failed transaction hash? Failed transactions revert any state change so smart contracts can't offer refunds becase they will be reversed. As said by Kof you are charged for the blockchain usage, not for the failed exchange. Before sending any transaction wallets usually calculate how much the transaction will cost and ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

No, as miners still spend CPU power a failed tx, they have to be compensated.

If failed transactions were free, it would be possible to attack miners and spam the network by spamming failed transactions.

Comment: Well, then a smart contract / 0x should refund, no? Wasn't talking about miners. 0x failed, has to refund?

Comment: It runs on the blockchain, so it can't refund...

Comment: 0x charges fees on swaps, right? So, they have a treasury, right? If their smart contract failed and customer was charged by miners, they can refund by simply sending eth from treasury to the customer wallet, right?

Comment: Anybody from 0x here? Anything to say?

Comment: Did you read their Terms of Service..? https://www.0x.org/terms

Comment: Of course, I did. I always discuss them with my lawyer even when I need to make a swap.

Comment: Not gonna sue 0x over $300, simply won't use it. Seems like scammy dex, never use again.

Comment: If it's decentralized, suing 0x wouldn't do much...